# Aggregation error: The field 'planet' must be an accumulator object

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to run the below code, but got this error.
`OperationFailure: The field 'planet' must be an accumulator object, full error: {'operationTime': Timestamp(1614568170, 1), 'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': "The field 'planet' must be an accumulator object", 'code': 40234, 'codeName': 'Location40234', '$clusterTime': {'clusterTime': Timestamp(1614568170, 1), 'signature': {'hash': b'\xa4\xd9\xcd\xae\xd9\x91\x05G;{L\x8d8\xaf\xea\xca\x03\xe9\xd5\xc6', 'keyId': 6902062171803353090}}} SEARCH`

When I removed this part

```
                    "count":{"$first":"$count"},
                    "letter":{"$first":"$_id.planet"}
                        },
```

then it works just fine, but did not give me what I expected.

This is what I expect:
[image: sample output]

Here is my try:

```
pipeline = [
            {"$group":{
                "_id":{"planet":"$system.planet.letter",
                       "numbers_of_planets":"$system.numbers_of_planets"},
                "count":{"$sum":1}
            }},
            {"$sort":{"count":-1,"_id.planet":1}},
            {"$group":{
                "_id":"$_id.numbers_of_planets",
                "planet":{
                    "count":{"$first":"$count"},
                    "letter":{"$first":"$_id.planet"}
                        },
                "grouping_count":{"$sum":1},
                "total":{"$sum":"$planet.count"}
            }},
        {"$sort": {"numbers_of_planets":-1}},  
        {"$limit":3}     
]

show_table(exoplanets.aggregate(pipeline))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `"errmsg" : "The field 'planet' must be an accumulator object"`

The error is in the following group stage:

```
    {"$group":{
        "_id":"$_id.numbers_of_planets",
        "planet":{
            "count":{"$first":"$count"},
            "letter":{"$first":"$_id.planet"}
         },
        "grouping_count":{"$sum":1},
        "total":{"$sum":"$planet.count"}
    }},
```

Specifically, in this snippet:

```
    "planet":{
        "count":{"$first":"$count"},
        "letter":{"$first":"$_id.planet"}
     },
```

MongoDB is expecting a [group accumulator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#accumulators-group) operator (e.g., `$first`, `$sum`, etc.) after the field `"planet"`, where you are providing this: `"planet": { "count" ...`; hence the error. You need to solve the idea you have like this, by adding an additional `$addFields` stage:

```
{ "$group":{
     "_id": "$_id.numbers_of_planets",
     "planet_count": { "$first": "$count" },
     "planet_letter": { "$first": "$_id.planet" },
     "grouping_count": { "$sum": 1 },
     "total": { "$sum": "$planet.count" }
}},
{ "$addFields": { 
      "planet" : { "count": "$planet_count", "letter": "$planet_letter" }, 
      "planet_count": "$$REMOVE",  
      "planet_letter":  "$$REMOVE"
} }, 
// other stages ...
```